# install opencv with cuda support and.. brew

Tags: homebrew, gpu

i have installed opencv with brew and everything is magically ok. now i want to try to recompile by myself with cuda support.

for this i have to download opencv, change a line in CMakeList.txt (because i have already installed cuds 5 and cuda toolkit), run cmake, run make, run make install. Exactly what brew has done.

I am scared to do some mess with brew and blabla and going end up to have 2 different version of opencv and brew not happy.

I just compile opencv with `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` so pkg-config is the only thing i care about.

What is the best way to do it without mess everything up?

Comment: The reason to use other packaging systems rather than brew is that they leave /usr/local for this sort of thing - It might be easiest to use one of these e.g. macports,  fink ratherthan brew if you are going totry your own builds

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` option to `cmake` to have OpenCV install to a different location. It's analagous to `./configure --prefix`. For example:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/reallylocal -D WITH_CUDA ..
```

This will install it under `/opt/reallylocal`, leaving `/usr/local` untouched. Then, to run your custom build, call it with the full path, or put the appropriate directories on your PATH and PYTHONPATH variables when working with it. If you build other projects against your opencv, you'll need to point their build scripts at your custom install location. Leave those paths alone when doing `brew` tasks and other work, and `brew` won't care about your other install off to the side.

The [OpenCV Install Guide](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide) has full details.

I tested this on my OS X 10.8.3 box. `/usr` stayed clean.

```
[✘ @ in ~/tmp/homebrew/opencv/install]
$ find /usr > before-install.txt
find: /usr/sbin/authserver: Permission denied
... did the whole build & install in another terminal ...
[✘ @ in ~/tmp/homebrew/opencv/install]
$ find /usr > after-install.txt
find: /usr/sbin/authserver: Permission denied
[✘ @ in ~/tmp/homebrew/opencv/install]
$ diff before-install.txt after-install.txt
[@ in ~/tmp/homebrew/opencv/install]
$
```

Comment: which compiler are using? c++ with llvm backend? which version?